# service mysql reload results 'Access denied', but service mysql start works

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3, debian, mysqladmin

Using Debian 10.10.

I have a MySQL problem.

```
service mysql reload
```

results 'Access denied'

```
service mysql start
```

executes correctly.

All databases are working correctly after starting mysql. Strange, that reloading results access denied error.

Connecting to mysql with

```
mysql -p -u root -h localhost
```

connects successfully.

Only mysqladmin has problems:

```
mysqladmin start
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

mysqladmin reload
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Any idea what is the problem with mysqladmin?
Maybe some permission problem?

Comment: Include `show create user root@locahost`. What linux user are you running `mysqladmin` as?

Comment: I execute mysqladmin as root. I have mysql root user and it has password assigned. I can login with mysql client as shown in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

There are two items to note here:

1. `service {daemon} reload` will reload their configuration files if they're already running. If the service is not running, then an error will be returned.

   One option would be to use `reload-or-restart` instead, as this will check if the service is running and take the appropriate action:

   ```
   sudo service mysqld reload-or-restart
   ```

   Alternatively, you could just use `restart` as this is faster to type and will almost always do the correct thing.
2. MySQLAdmin cannot use a SQL root account unless you connect via [the Unix Socket plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/). A simpler method may be to create a separate administrator account, grant it full privileges, and connect via that user account.